# Trouble setting up Rails custom form helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, form-helpers

I'm trying to create a custom form helper method (for customizing an HTML checkbox tag), and I'm having some issues with it. I've created the following helper, `wrapped_check_box`

```
module FormHelper
  class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper

    def wrapped_check_box(name, options = {})
      raw "<div class='checkbox-wrapper'>" + \
        check_box_tag(@object_name, name, options) + \
        "<span class='checkbox-check'></span>" + \
      "</div>"
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

`<%= f.wrapped_check_box :receives_updates %>`

When I use it, in this example from a new `User` model, I get the following output:

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" name="user" id="user" value="receives_updates" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkbox-check"></span>
</div>
```

Two issues here:

1. The field is auto-checked, even when I pass in `checked: false`
2. This appears to be the incorrect `id` value, which messes things up with `<label>` tags, and everything in general

I've been following various articles to piece this together, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated :)

**Update**

I made some progress by updating the `check_box_tag` method:

```
check_box_tag("#{@object_name}[#{name.to_s}]", 1, options)
```

Now outputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user[receives_updates]" id="user_receives_updates" value="1" checked="checked">
```

That's exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately it still always outputs `checked="checked"`, even when I pass it in as false.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats is the value you are expecting for `id`

Comment: @Abhinay a regular `f.check_box` outputs `user_receives_updates` as `id`, which is the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the docs for `check_box_tag`, and understood it a bit more. I ended up going with this:

```
module FormHelper
  def wrapped_check_box_tag(name, value=1, checked=false, options={})
    raw "<div class='checkbox-wrapper'>" + \
      check_box_tag(name, value, checked, options) + \
      "<span class='checkbox-checks'></span>" + \
    "</div>"
  end

  class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    include FormHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper

    def wrapped_check_box(name, options = {})
      wrapped_check_box_tag("#{@object_name}[#{name.to_s}]", options[:value], options[:checked], options)
    end
  end
end
```

This now makes a global method, as well as a form helper available:

`<%= wrapped_check_box_tag :accepts_terms %>`

`<%= f.wrapped_check_box :receives_updates, { checked: true } %>`

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears!